# If the app is suspended while NSTimer is running, will it crash upon reopening?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer, cllocationmanager

Theres something that is making my app crash between when it gets suspended and when it's reopened. It's a location based app that uses the didUpdateLocations callback/delegate function. I have one or two timers running in the background, and i'm not really sure what happens to them when the app is minimized.

I've been doing some thinking. Really, if the timers aren't running in the background that's fine; they dont need to be. But are they getting suspended, and when the app pulls back up they try to catch up to where they were or something? Why does my app crash when i reopen it?

It's not as simple as crashing when it reopens either. It works if it's a normal amount of time. The app is made to run in the background indefinitely, within reason, so if i wait a day or two before opening it again, it crashes on me. Doesn't crash, necessarily, but freezes. It doesnt send a crash report, just sits there and does nothing. I cant interact with the UI or anything. What could be causing it to do this?

Like i said, the only things that run "indefinitely" are the didUpdateLocations method and one or two timers that check things. That's program flow. It all stems from that. I can offer some code or more information if anybody needs it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to debug this behaviour? You can put a breakpoint and see where it's getting stuck. Also, without code it's very hard to know what's going on

Comment: Your timers will fire once for each increment that they have missed since the app was last opened.

Comment: Your timers run on the same thread they were created so if you created them on the main UI thread I think you should be fine. I would recommend integrating a crash reporting system so your crash log will be sent to you when you reopen your app. It could save a lot of guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by lehn0058, the timers fire once for each missed increment when the app opens. This is potentially disastrous, and sounds like if the timer isn't set up to count down to something, it should probably be invalidated and restarted each time the app is opened and closed. Another option that i discovered recently is software called Flurry. It's analytical software that i recently integrated into my app. Potentially extremely useful; others should look into it if they havent heard of it.